# Python importing package in function

Tags: python, numpy, import, package, knn

I am writing a code for finding the K Nereast Neighbour, and need to use the numPy Python package for calculations . I am attaching the function code below :

```
#Import packages
import numpy as np

def knn(Q,R,k,classvar):
#Function that does k-NN and selects the k Nearest Neighbours
#Input parameters
#Q array of Query points, R array of reference points
#k is the no of closest points in k-NN
#classvar is binary class variable either 1 or 0


#for loop over all Query points
#calculate distance from ith Query point to all reference points
        dist = np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, R-Q)
#sort distances and find indexes
        index=np.argsort(dist)
#pick the kth closest indexes
        knearest=index[1:k]
#find the count of 1's and 0's in the binary class variable
#if count of 1 is more than count of 0 predict class 1 else class 0
        if sum(e==0) > sum(e==1):
           preclassQ=0;
        else:
           preclassQ=1;
        return preclassQ
```

First I want to know, is it necessary to include the statement

```
from numpy import *
```

in the function definition, it we are going to give it in the iPython command line ?

I saved this code as knn.py, then imported it in the command line and called the function as follows :

```
In [58]: import knn

In [59]: knn.knn(b,a,1,[(0),( 0),( 1),( 1)])
```

But the function does not execute and I get an error as follows !:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/Project/<ipython console> in <module>()

/Project/knn.py in knn(Q, R, k, classvar)
     14         dist = np.apply_along_axis(np.linalg.norm, 1, R-Q)
     15 #sort distances and find indexes

---> 16         index=np.argsort(dist)
     17 #pick the kth closest indexes

     18         knearest=index[1:k]

NameError: global name 'numpy' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `np.some_function` you don't have to use `from numpy import *`.

The local definitions of the function must be in conflict with the global definitions, so try moving `import numpy` inside the function:

```
def knn(Q, R, k, classvar):
    import numpy as np
```

If it does not work, somewhere you must be using `numpy.some_function` instead of `np.some_function`...

Answer (score 0):

Before importing the package 'numpy'

```
import numpy as np
```

you can define np as global

```
global np
```

The code will go like this

```
global np
import numpy as np

def foo():
    np.seterr(divide = 'ignore')
```

this worked for me, might work for you as well!!!